# place a left/right span on the same line so no space

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a website and I need the menu on the left content box on the right.

```
#Wrapper { 
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    top: 10px;
}


span.left {
    position: relative;
    left: -365px;
    top: 400px;
    z-index:1;
}


span.right {
    position: relative;
    right: -74px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Every time I add a new image under the left span, the top of the right span goes down lower because they're not on the same line. I still want relative positioning, but I want the two spans to be on top of eachother.

Comment: Do you mean they should be next to each, or do you want one to be directly on top of the other so one is not visible? Your question is kind of vague. Make (at jsfiddle.net) a diagram of what you're looking for because I'm having trouble picturing it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use floats:

```
span.right {
     float: right;
}
span.left {
     float: left;
}
```

and then at the bottom of the wrapper ad the following:

```
<div style="clear: both; height: 0">&nbsp;</div>
```

To make the wrapper the same height as the tallest floated div

Comment: i need images to overlap the content area, the image active will be ontop of a table with the border to give the apperance that the nav box is open with the content box as one seamingless border

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you're trying to accomplish. Do you mean like drop down menu? This would be a lot easier to figure out if you could give me something to look at; try to set up something at jsfiddle.net that can be looked at and link to it.

Comment: display: inline-block; << this code for both spans works well, i just position the nav 1px to go ontop of the table

Comment: Adding details like that doesn't help me understand what you're trying to do. You have not given an effective overall picture of exactly what you want to achieve.